# (PhoneGap): Div overlay is not blocking events beneath it.

Tags: android, html, cordova, overlay

I am creating application for Android using PhoneGap (with jQuery mobile).

I want that after clicking some certain button div overlay would show. It managed it with no problem. The thing is that everything underneath that div should not react on click (should be not accessible at all). Unfortunately all the events can be fired and even input/textarea fields can be edited.

Here is some CSS code for created div:

```
#shopBoxOuter{

    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Is there other option to deal with that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's probably happening because of [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Examples#Example_5%3a_Event_Propagation). Try binding an on click event to the pop-up, and include `event.stopPropagation()` or if that doesn't work `event.preventDefault()`, which cancels the event.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know how to bind tap function to catch the event for #shopBoxOuter because it is created dynamically. I tried something like that (but it is not working):

 `$("#units").bind("tap", function() {  
    var outerDiv = $('<div>', {id: 'shopBoxOuter'});  
    //code below doesn't work  
    outerDiv.bind("tap", function() {  
        alert("blocked");  
    });  
  
    $("body").append(outerDiv);  
});`

Comment: That should work, though I think it's more common practice to use $().on instead of .bind now. I assume you're making sure to do the binding when the document is ready?

Comment: Yes.
`$(#units).bind` is working because it creates the outerDiv in body. The only part which doesn't work is `outerDiv.bind` because if I tap on that div event is not fired. $().on is better than .bind?

Comment: outerDiv behaves like transparent to touch, because if instead `outerDiv.bind` I do `$("body").bind("tap", function(e) { alert(e.target.id)` I get the id of any element which is under the outerDiv.

Comment: $().on is virtually the same thing, I believe in the recent versions of jQuery .bind actually uses .on. The only real difference is that .bind might be removed in the future, which could possibly break something. I used the code you have there in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curlystraw/dkLTw/2/), and it appears to work. What kind of styling is on the div you're creating?